# Kony - Failed to publish Application for 'Services'

Tags: temenos-quantum

Trying to publish an app to Kony cloud and i am seeing the below error on logs. Please help to overcome the below error.

```
[01-10-2016 11:04:24]{
  "status_long_message": "Request conflict.",
  "status_short_message": "Conflict",
  "message": "Application or service with name 'Services' already exists",
  "status": "error",
  "status_code": 409
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your application id to some else than services and also rename your application name, Build the app again and try publishing it to cloud, that should work.